# Count unique records in database

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably an easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer on here.  I have written a query that yields a list of email addresses.  The list has duplicate records, so I did a "GROUP BY email" so that I could print out a list of only unique values.  I also need the count of unique emails so that my loop works properly.  How do I get that number?  mysql_num_rows is giving the total including duplicate emails.

Comment: Edit your question and add your code.  Check out the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT( email ) ) FROM table
```