# MySQL: Add a "Total" Count to the last row of SQL Query for Unique value only

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

**Info:**  Server version: 5.1.39  / MySQL / phpMyAdmin
**Php:**  5.4
**Server:**  Apache
**Code is run via:** Server SQL Query (copy & paste in the phpMyAdmin) or in MySQL Workbench or using a custom shopping cart manager.
**Exports to:** Excel (.csv then to .xlsx for sales reports)
**Other:** I do use a number of tables for referencing

**Question**
I want to add a sub-total to the bottom (or top) row of my SQL Query.  I am wanting to count Unique Order numbers only.  Either as a whole, or by my date query.

This works, but puts it in 1 row, 1 column then does not generate the rest of my query.

`COUNT( DISTINCT( T5.orders_id ) ) As OrdUnique,`

Returns:

```
OrdUnique  |  OrdID  |  ProdName  |  etc  
2342       |  21     |  Name      |  Rest of data
```

**What I would like is:**

```
OrdID  |  ProdName  |  Qty  | etc
2525   |    prod    |  1    |  
2538   |    prod    |  1    |  
2553   |    prod    |  1    |  
2553   |    prod    |  1    |  
2538   |    prod    |  1    |  

OrdUnq = 3
```

The basic structure of my existing code is:

```
Select
T5.orders_id As OrdID,
T3.products_name As ProdName,   
T2.products_quantity As Qty,  

more content  
even more content (about 70 lines of query)  
ends with (similar)  

From /*PREFIX*/products T1
Left Join /*PREFIX*/orders_products T2 On (T1.products_id = T2.products_id)
Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)
Left Join /*PREFIX*/manufacturers T4 On (T1.manufacturers_id = T4.manufacturers_id)
Where (T5.date_purchased >= 20120101) And (T5.date_purchased <= 20131216) And T5.orders_status = x 
Order By T5.orders_id
```

**Notes:**
I do not run this via PHP, it is simply a copy & paste from my .sql/.txt file in to the backend of my server OR through MySQL Workbench

Throws a table access error
`(select COUNT( DISTINCT( T5.orders_id ) ) from T5.orders) As OrdUnique,`

Throws a Error Code: 1242: subquery returns more than one row
`(select COUNT( DISTINCT( T5.orders_id ) ) as OrdUnq FROM orders GROUP BY orders_id WITH ROLLUP),`
(as seen here: [Calculate the total time duration on last row in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306032/calculate-the-total-time-duration-on-last-row-in-mysql))

This also does not work:
[Count unique records in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274592/count-unique-records-in-database)

Thank you in advance for your insight.

Comment: making a `UNION` with a secon query having the `COUNT` clause would be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is not very efficient, but an easy solution woudl be to use this query:

```
    SELECT null as total,
           T5.orders_id As OrdID,
           T3.products_name As ProdName,   
           T2.products_quantity As Qty
      From /*PREFIX*/products T1
 Left Join /*PREFIX*/orders_products T2 On (T1.products_id = T2.products_id)
Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)
 Left Join /*PREFIX*/manufacturers T4 On (T1.manufacturers_id = T4.manufacturers_id)
     Where (T5.date_purchased >= 20120101) 
       And (T5.date_purchased <= 20131216) 
       And T5.orders_status = 'x' 
  Order By T5.orders_id
     UNION
    SELECT count(*) AS total,
           null As OrdID,
           null As ProdName,   
           null As Qty
      FROM (select T5.orders_id
              From /*PREFIX*/products T1
         Left Join /*PREFIX*/orders_products T2 On (T1.products_id = T2.products_id)
        Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)
         Left Join /*PREFIX*/manufacturers T4 On (T1.manufacturers_id = T4.manufacturers_id)
             Where (T5.date_purchased >= 20120101) 
               And (T5.date_purchased <= 20131216) 
               And T5.orders_status = 'x' 
          GROUP BY T5.orders_id
          ) as s
```

Pay attention to `UNION` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: the select statements, in union, need to have the same number of columns. So the second query needs to be modified to something like `SELECT  '' As OrdID, '' As ProdName, count(*) AS qty `

Comment: @Oscar thank you. I have copied & pasted, added my full joins & `AND`'s and I get MySQL WOrkbench error message:  Incorrect usage of `UNION` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: @melc Does that mean I need to copy & paste my entire query a 2nd time AFTER the `UNION`?

Comment: @MrsAdmin just the select part, since the number of columns needs to be the same.

Comment: Edited, could you please retry it?

Comment: @OscarPérez I must be doing something wrong. It works (in a fashion) it now adds another column and states how many times that OrdID shows up.  `3  2629  Product`  That's right, there were 3 lines on that order making 2629 generate 3 times in the query.  It's not giving me a row OrdID count from 0->3000.

Comment: @MrsAdmin , if I get it right, the first part of the query (before `UNION`) shoud show you the same data as before, but with a new column called `total` (with a value of null). Then, you should have a new row at he end with all the fields with `null` values except the first one, which will show the number of distinct orders selected. Is it working this way?

Comment: @MrsAdmin if you execute:  `SELECT count(*) AS total,
           null As OrdID,
           null As ProdName,   
           null As Qty
      From /*PREFIX*/products T1
 Left Join /*PREFIX*/orders_products T2 On (T1.products_id = T2.products_id)
Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)
 Left Join /*PREFIX*/manufacturers T4 On (T1.manufacturers_id = T4.manufacturers_id)
     Where (T5.date_purchased >= 20120101) 
       And (T5.date_purchased <= 20131216) 
       And T5.orders_status = 'x' 
  GROUP BY T5.orders_id`

You obtain the corrent number of orders?

Comment: @OscarPérez, sorry.  :(  I now have 9 additional rows, with the 'TOTAL' column 1 2 3 4 5 6 13 12 14.   I thought it might be counting unique ProdID not OrderID, but that's not right :(  I'm missing something, i'm sorry.

Comment: When I put my original query in to CSV/Excel I get 2342 unique OrdIDs.  So I know what the answer should be :)

Comment: What is the value given by the second part of the query (after the `UNION`) if executed alone?

Comment: @OscarPérez it is giving me in the 'total' column the product count still.  So, if there are 4 products, it produces 4 rows, the Unique OrdID is repeated 4 times.  The count in total shows 4.   --  It looks like we're missing the Count Unique.

Comment: Please, try with the current edit. As you can see, I changed the post-`UNION` part

Comment: @OscarPérez We got there in the end!  It works! I've been trying it out with some different formulas and so far it's what I need, thank you so much for your patience and perseverance with the problem and with me.  +10 ;)

Comment: Happy to have been useful!